# Extension function that returns the list that contains specific listtype as parameter

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to write an extension function that takes a List of UserList and returns the UserList which ListType matches the function parameter. How could I do this?
This is what I've written but it is not correct:

```
    fun List<UserList>.filter(listType: ListType): UserList = this.filter { userList ->
      when (listType) {
        ListType.UNKNOWN -> true
        else -> userList.listType == listType
      }
    }
```

**UserList.kt** (this class cannot be modified)

```
data class UserList(
  @SerializedName("id") val id: Int = DEFAULT_ID,
  @SerializedName("name") val name: String = "",
  @SerializedName("type") val _listType: ListType? = ListType.DEFAULT,
  @SerializedName("categories") val categories: List<Category> = listOf(),
) {

  companion object {
    const val DEFAULT_ID = -1
  }

  val listType: ListType
    get() = _listType ?: UNKNOWN

  enum class ListType {
    @SerializedName("unknown")
    UNKNOWN,
    @SerializedName("products")
    PRODUCTS,
    @SerializedName("favourites")
    FAVORITES,
    @SerializedName("lists")
    LISTS;

    companion object {
      val DEFAULT: ListType = UNKNOWN
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code

```
fun List<UserList>.filter(listType: ListType): UserList = this.filter { userList ->
  when (listType) {
    ListType.UNKNOWN -> true
    else -> userList.listType == listType
  }
}
```

You are returning a list of UserList but the return type is just a single UserList

To return a list of UserList change to this

```
fun List<UserList>.filter(listType: ListType): List <UserList> = this.filter { userList ->
  when (listType) {
    ListType.UNKNOWN -> true
    else -> userList.listType == listType
  }
}
```

For your answer, to return a single value, use this method

```
fun List<UserList>.filter(listType: ListType): UserList = this.first { userList ->
  when (listType) {
    ListType.UNKNOWN -> true
    else -> userList.listType == listType
  }
}
```